# Game Programming Performance

Tags: java, android, iphone, performance

I have narrowed down my slowdowns to this method

```
public void drawMap(Canvas canvas) {

    if (car.x > 0 && map != null) {
        clipArea = Bitmap.createBitmap(map, mapx, mapy, getWidth(),
                getHeight());
        canvas.drawBitmap(clipArea, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

This is taking about 3 seconds to run! any help would be appreciated the bitmap is about twice the size of the screen but this is key to my game so I need to keep this :) any help on optimising? thanks

Answer (score 0):

you always wait a fixed time here, independent of how long the whole calculations and ui updates take

```
 frame.postDelayed(frameUpdate, FRAME_RATE);
```

what you want to do is: before the new "game tick" you create a timestamp variable,
then you do the calculations, and then you check how much time is left until the next tick should be.

something like this:

```
synchronized public void run() {


    Date timestamp = new Date();

    // do your calculations
    ...

    // calculate how much time it took and when the next update should be:
    int timeToNextTick = FRAME_RATE - (new Date().getTime() - timestamp.getTime());
    frame.postDelayed(frameUpdate, timeToNextTick);

}
```

this way, the update ticks should always be equally timed (assumed that the device is capable of running the code within the framerate value)

Comment: Hi I found this very interesting so decided to see what FPS i was actually getting and to get 50fps is taking around 6 seconds! Is this down to what you said or my code? as this is a top down racing game I don't see how it is running that slow :(

Comment: Ok now I was measuring I have narrowed it down to drawing the background! Please see edit